# In input function, how to make sure the user only enter number with exactly 2 decimals places?

Tags: python, input, decimal, rounding

When I use input function,how to make sure the user only enters number with two decimal places? And no str, no list...., only enter numbers. 
my code:

```
a = round(input("num: "),2)
```

expexted output :

```
num: 3.55
num: 4.00
num: 32.40
```

Comment: Do you mean how to make sure the *user* only enters two decimal places? You can check the format of the string, e.g. using regex, before parsing to float.

Comment: yeah! you are right !@jonrsharpej

Answer (score 1):

`input` does not automatically handle what to expect from user. You can write a conditional evaluation of what the user has inputted:

```
try:
    inp = input("num: ")
    if f'{float(inp):.2f}' == inp:
        print('Good to go')
    else:
        print('Your input does not contain exactly 2 decimal places')
except ValueError:
    print('Only numbers allowed')
```

Note if you need to read again from user on a falsy note, wrap the whole thing in a `while True:` loop.

**Sample run**:

```
>>> num: 4
Your input does not contain exactly 2 decimal places
>>> num: something
Only numbers allowed
>>> num: 4.567
Your input does not contain exactly 2 decimal places
>>> num: 4.00
Good to go
```